# Cannot implicitly convert type when adding pin to MapControl

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, uwp-maps

I'm trying to add a pin to a MapControl dynamically but it's not working despite using an import statement (`using`). `new Point(0.5, 1)` in `NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1)` returns the following error. What's the correct way to resolve this?

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.Foundation.Point' to 'System.Drawing.Point'

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TownTraveller.Data;
using TownTraveller.UserControls;
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var mapPage = new MapPage();

        var pinUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/MapPin.png");

        var myMapControl = pageMap.MyMapControl;

        var mapCenter =
           new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
           {
               Latitude = 51053881,
               Longitude = -0.100239
           });
        myMapControl.Center = mapCenter;

        myMapControl.ZoomLevel = 10;

        var MapPoints = new List<PointOfInterest>();
        var mapPin1 = new PointOfInterest
        {
            PinName = "Pin1",
            DisplayName = "Place One",
            ImageSourceUri = pinUri,
            ),
            Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
            {
                Latitude = 51.486223,
                Longitude = -0.124474
            })

        };

        MapPoints.Add(mapPin1);
    }
}
```

**'PointOfInterest' class**

```
public class PointOfInterest
{
    public string PinName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public Uri ImageSourceUri { get; set; }
    public Point NormalizedAnchorPoint { get; set; }
    public Geopoint Location { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.Foundation.Point' to 'System.Drawing.Point'

The problem is `NormalizedAnchorPoint` property is using `System.Drawing` namespace. And you could add the full namespace `Windows.Foundation.Point`  for `NormalizedAnchorPoint` to specific it's type like the following.

```
public class PointOfInterest
{
    public string PinName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public Uri ImageSourceUri { get; set; }
    public Windows.Foundation.Point NormalizedAnchorPoint { get; set; }
    public Geopoint Location { get; set; }
}
```